# how i can use union and union all in Doctrine1.2

Tags: doctrine-1.2

SELECT avg(mw) as av FROM meter_reading WHERE   hierarchy_id in(1,2) and 
union all SELECT avg(elec) as av FROM meter_reading WHERE  hierarchy_id in(1,2) (Example)

Answer (score 0):

Union is not supported in Doctrine 1.2.
Only chance is to execute raw sql via

```
$statement = $conn->getDbh()->prepare('SELECT ... ');
$statement->execute($params);
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
```

which baisically work like php PDO.